# Simple ng-click not working in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to call a function in click function from my html page ,
added all typescript definition files from nuget but something is going wrong
My Click Function is not Working .... No error in console even

Here is my Hrml and Controller Code

**Html Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="testModule">
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <input type="button" ng-click="click()" value="test" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("testModule", []);

class test {

    constructor() { }

    click() {

        alert();
    }
} 


angular.module("testModule").controller("test", test );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This does not work because `ng-click="click()"` tries to call `$scope.click()` which is not defined.

I would highly advise you to use the [`controller as`](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)-Syntax when working with AngularJS and Typescript

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbgndf23/)

Comment: Thanks bro, Was breaking my head for around 2hrs , such a nasty mistake ..I usually use app.js routing and define there controller with alias vm but forgot the basics when implenting in a page! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the corrected code. Don't mark this as the answer, @Aides got here before me.

Html Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <!-- its 2016 -->
<head>
   <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>

   <script src="test.js"></script>
   <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="testModule">
   <div ng-controller="Test as test">
       <input type="button" ng-click="test.click()" value="test" />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
angular.module("testModule", []);

class Test {

    click() {
        alert();
    }
} 

angular.module("testModule").controller("Test", Test );
```

Comment: I don't mark it as answer :-p but thanks for taking your time and briefly posting answer!